# Blender Rigid Body Simulation freezing in the air

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Im working on a lego animation, and in one scene a castle gets broken into lots of peices. when i run the simulation instead of the bricks landing on the ground, they pretend they have a different floor. Does anyone know whats wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: Check for Rigid body cache frame range, maybe it is default 250 limit

Comment: You can also try applying Scale for Rigid Body and Collision objects.

Comment: The Cache frame range isn't the problem, it has plenty of time to hit the ground. I also don't want to change the scale of objects due to all the keyframes everything has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, what was wrong was that the floor of the simulation was a bounding box mesh. Thanks for the help though

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you have found a solution to your problem. This might help others that run into the same problem in the future :)

Comment: yea sorry, i had to wait 9 hours before accepting my own answer

Comment: My bad, I wasn't aware of that restriction :)